# MongoDB downgrade from 2.1 to 2.0

Tags: mongodb, downgrade

I made some tests with MongoDB 2.1 (unstable debian package). I want to test the code with 2.0 stable to see the speed difference.

Can I simply uninstall  mongoDB 2.1 and reinstall 2.0 without caring about the data ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use the data files created in 2.1 with 2.0.  You could also download a suitable Linux version from [mongodb.org/downloads](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) and install this in a separate directory if you want to run a comparison of both versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Stennie replied the question with his comment. I tried and it worked. On the mopngoDB website, the best is to download the legacy-static witch is very usefull for version testing.
Be sure  to put the right data path to mongod ;-)